# How can I use the "add Rows" feature to my datatables?

Tags: jquery, symfony, datatables, twig, rows

This is my datatable. It is working fine:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
     <thead>
          <tr>
            {% for key, value in columns %}
               <th>
                  {{ key }}
               </th>
            {% endfor %}
          <th width="100">Aktion</th>
          </tr>
     </thead>
</table>
```

script:

```
 var table = $('.table').DataTable({
    "ajax": {
      "url": "../data/data.json",
      "dataSrc": ""
    },

    "columns": [
      {% for key, value in columns %}
      {   "data": "{{ key }}"},
      {% endfor %}
      { "data": "uniqueId" }
    ]
  });
```

I want to add now the the feature "add rows". So I am adding this code:

```
  var counter = 1;

  $('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
      table.row.add( [
          counter +'.1',
          counter +'.2',
          counter +'.3',
          counter +'.4'

      ]).draw( false );

      counter++;
  } );

  // Automatically add a first row of data
  $('#addRow').click();
```

But when I load the page new I get the following error message (I did not click yet any button):

> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Requested unknown
>   parameter 'id' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this
>   error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the solution:

```
var counter = 1;

$('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
   table.row.add({
        {% for key, value in columns %}
        "{{ key }}": counter,
        {% endfor %}
   }).draw();
   counter++;
});
```